# MySQL view returns more than one row error when executed

Tags: mysql, statistics, average, rating

I have a view that keeps returning this error:

> subquery returns more than one row

I am not good with sql and I am looking for a layman's explanation on why this happening and how I can solve it. My code is below:

```
Create View `RestaurantRatings` AS    
    SELECT
        p.restaurantName,
    (SELECT count(r.restaurantID) FROM RestaurantReviews) / (SELECT count(DISTINCT r.restaurantID) FROM RestaurantReviews) AS avg_num_votes,
    (SELECT avg(r.rating) FROM RestaurantReviews) AS avg_rating,
    count(r.restaurantID) as num_votes,
    avg(r.rating) as rating
FROM
    Restaurants p,
    RestaurantReviews r
where
     p.restaurantID = r.restaurantID
GROUP BY 
    restaurantName
```

All I want is to retrieve the ratings from the database using the Bayesian formula which I have been googling for the past couple of hours and I am not winning.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Strange, might be a misleading error, that is not how external values are usually referenced in subqueries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a tricky error, caused by a subtle problem in your query.  Consider:

```
(SELECT count(r.restaurantID) FROM RestaurantReviews)
```

You think this is doing an aggregation.  However, it is not, because `r.restaurantId` is from the outer query, so even the `count()` is from the outer query.  You *could* fix this by removing or adjusting the aliases in the subqueries.

Instead, just write a proper aggregation query with a proper join.  The query would be something like this:

```
Create View `RestaurantRatings` AS    
    SELECT p.restaurantName,
           count(r.restaurantID) / count(DISTINCT r.restaurantID) AS avg_num_votes,
           avg(r.rating) AS avg_rating,
           count(r.restaurantID) as num_votes,
    FROM Restaurants p left join
         RestaurantReviews r
         on p.restaurantID = r.restaurantID
    GROUP BY  restaurantName;
```

I'm not exactly sure what you intend with the subqueries *and* the join.  The above is a better place to start, though.

Comment: Dude, Ill buy you a cupcake one day, thanks for pointing that out. That worked perfectly man